# What does "All-stars" mean?

Tags: idioms, translation

What does All-star mean in for example Dota All Stars or All star Superman? I am russian speaker so i think it some kind of english idiom, because direct translation doesn't make any sense.

Comment: A 'star' refers not just to a far off sun twinkling in the night sky, but also a person who stands out in glory—either for their skill, fame or whatever (think "sports star", "movie star" and so on.) So a group of "all stars" is, in theory, one comprised of members who are all considered brilliant at their craft. An all-star sporting team would be a team made up of the very best athletes.

Comment: *[All-star](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=all-star)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All-stars is a team made up of star (the best) players. Often it's an exhibition team made of retired famous players rather than a regular team